# Creation of a score system in unity

Tags: c#, mobile, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am currently developing a simple 2D game to learn many things about game development.

Nevertheless, I have some issues to create a score system.

I want to update the score every second, and adding 1 point for each second, and stop the count when the game is over.

I start to write this

```
public class scoremanager : MonoBehaviour {

    public int score;
    public GUIText distance;

    void Start () {
        score = 0;
    }

    void Update () {
        StartCoroutine(updateScoreManager(1f, 1));
        distance.text = score.ToString();
    }

    IEnumerator updateScoreManager(float totalTime, int amount) {
        score += amount; 
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (totalTime);
    }
}
```

The issues are that nothing shows up in the GUIText so I don't know if it works. And how can I stop the count when the game is over?

Comment: This seems to be some C++-like code. What has it to do with Java? Apart form this, the code is poorly formatted and you should describe, what the observed behaviour is. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may help you to improve your question(s).

Comment: I removed the tag - this is C#.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. What do i want is to add 1 point in a score (called distance) for each second left in the game. When the game is over, the count stop and the score is display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess simple solution to your problem is [InvokeRepeating](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html)

```
//Invokes the method methodName in time seconds, then repeatedly every repeatRate seconds.
public void InvokeRepeating(string methodName, float time, float repeatRate);
```

So your transfomed code colud be

public class scoremanager : MonoBehaviour {

```
public int score;
public GUIText distance;

void Start () {
   InvokeRepeating("updateScoreManager",1f,1f);
}

void Update () {
    distance.text = score.ToString();
}

void updateScoreManager() {
    score += 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, I think you should use uGUI since that's Unity's accepted solution for UI now: http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/28/overview-of-the-new-ui-system/

I can't really say what the problem is with your GUIText since I don't know if the position is off or whatever but I can tell you how to manage the counting better.

You don't need to use the Update function, using the update function defeats the purpose of using a Coroutine to update your text. Using a Coroutine gives you some control over when it starts Updating and when it stops. So one solution is to get rid of the Update function entirely so you can control it better:

```
public class scoremanager : MonoBehaviour {

    public int score;
    public GUIText distance;

    private Coroutine scoreCoroutine;

    void Start () {
        score = 0;
        scoreCoroutine = StartCoroutine(updateScoreManager(1f, 1));
    }

    IEnumerator updateScoreManager(float totalTime, int amount) {
        while(true) {
            score += amount; 
            distance.text = score.ToString();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (totalTime);
        }
    }

    // example of ending game
    void EndGame() {
        StopCoroutine(scoreCoroutine);
        scoreCoroutine = null;
    }
}
```

This might look weird (why am I using an infinite loop)? But that's the beauty of Coroutines, you can write code like this since the yield statement allows you to return from the code and come back to the same spot later. Normally a while loop would cause your game to crash, but a yield statement let's your create a time while loop!

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

I can see few glitches in your code. Let's cover it first.

- You are calling `Coroutine` in `Update` with delay time of 1 second. This means your `Coroutine` is executing 30 or 60 times per second.
- You are assigning text in `Update` too. This may be the reason that it refreshes the text (Not sure about this)
- In your `Coroutine` your delay i.e. `WaitForSeconds` is of no use here, as nothing is happening after that line of code.

I'm modifying your exact code so that you can understand that what you want can be achieved by this too :)

```
public class scoremanager : MonoBehaviour {

    public int score;
    public GUIText distance;
    public bool isGameOver = false;

    void Start () {
        score = 0;
        StartCoroutine(updateScoreManager(1f, 1));
    }

    void Update () {

    }

    IEnumerator updateScoreManager(float totalTime, int amount) {
        while(!isGameOver){
            score += amount; 
            distance.text = score.ToString();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (totalTime);
        }
    }
}
```

What are the changes...

- No code in `Update`.
- Call `Coroutine` only once.
- In `Coroutine` it is changing the `score` and `distance` both, once per `totalTime` second(s). Until the `isGameOver` flag is `false`. Just make it `true` when your game is over.

Comment: Hello, and thank you very much for correct my script. But i can see the score, because when i try to add my script as a component to the GUIText, it says "Can't add script component 'score manager' because the script class cannot be found. Make sure that there are no compile rrors and that the file name and class name match.", and i don't know why? :/

Comment: I used the script that you corrected, but when i tried to add it as a component, i have this error, so i can see if the script work or not

Comment: Can you provide whole script and line of adding component?

Comment: ` using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class scoremanager : MonoBehaviour {
 
 public int score;
 public GUIText distance;
 public bool isGameOver = false;
 
 void Start () {
  score = 0;
  StartCoroutine(updateScoreManager(1f, 1));
 }
 
 void Update () {
  
 }
 
 IEnumerator updateScoreManager(float totalTime, int amount) {
  while(!isGameOver){
   score += amount; 
   distance.text = score.ToString();
   yield return new WaitForSeconds (totalTime);
  }
 }
} `

Comment: Sorry bro, I m in fever for last 2 days. Well, can you also paste the add component line ?

Answer (score 0):

> The issues are that nothing shows up in the GUIText so I don't know if
>   it works

What happens? Is it always zero or nothing is displayed? If nothing - check coordinates, layer etc. to ensure you positioned it properly. Refere to http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-GUIText.html

> And how can I stop the count when the game is over?

Use `StopCoroutine(updateScoreManager)` on game over event and don't forget to set score to zero.

Actually saying your code design is not good. It would be great to implement **State**, **Observer**, **Component** patterns. With state you can implement game states like *Game, GameOver*. With Observer you can notify your scores component. With component you serve single responsibility principle by placing score logics to score component.

At least consider separate start game initialization, update component, and game over logics.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for your comment. when i try to add the script as a component for the GUIText, i have a screen error says "Can't add script component 'score manager' because the script class cannot be found. Make sure that there are no compile rrors and that the file name and class name match." I don't know why it shows that

Answer (score 0):

I'm going the skip the lecture on the pattern you are implementing because I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, but the source of your update problem is here:

```
IEnumerator updateScoreManager(float totalTime, int amount)
    {
        score += amount;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(totalTime);

    }
```

In practice, when I run into these kinds of issues I separate the failing logic from the source application to help reduce the amount of noise.

So, when I prototype your algorithim (code below) what happens is that score is always zero because the StartCoroutine should be using the return value of updateScoreManager to do the updating when ever .Update() is called.

If my prototyping seems to match how you are trying to implement this code, then I can post how I would fix this later.

But basically, instead of returning IEnumerator return an int that updates the score and that might get you past this issue.

Unless you can describe the use-case where you need the IEnumerator somewhere else in the codes?

Execute Prototype:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Ans34612672 Ans34612672 = new Ans34612672();
        Ans34612672.Execute();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Prototype Wrapper Class:

```
public class Ans34612672
{
    public Ans34612672()
    {

    }

    public bool Execute()
    {
        bool retValue = false;
        scoremanager Manager = new scoremanager();
        Manager.Start();
        while(Manager.score < 20)
        {
            Manager.Update();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(Manager.distance);
        Console.ReadKey();
        return retValue;
    }

}
```

Prototype Classes:

```
public class scoremanager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int score;
    public GUIText distance;

    public void Start()
    {
        score = 0;
        distance = new GUIText();
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        IEnumerator UpdateResults = updateScoreManager(1f, 1);
        StartCoroutine(UpdateResults);
        distance.text = score.ToString();

    }

    private void StartCoroutine(IEnumerator enumerator)
    {
        //Implement Logic
    }

    IEnumerator updateScoreManager(float totalTime, int amount)
    {
        score += amount;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(totalTime);

    }
}

internal class WaitForSeconds
{
    private float totalTime;

    public WaitForSeconds(float totalTime)
    {
        this.totalTime = totalTime;
    }
}

public class GUIText
{
    internal string text;
}

public class MonoBehaviour
{
}
```

Comment: hello Paul, thank you but i am completely lost with this amount of informations. I will try your script and give you a feeback. I hope it will work :)